# How do I schedule a task to run once?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

I want to delay doing something, along the lines of setting a countdown timer that will "do a thing" after a certain amount of time.

I want the rest of my program to keep running while I wait, so I tried making my own `Thread` that contained a one-minute delay:

```
public class Scratch {
    private static boolean outOfTime = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread countdown = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // wait a while
                    System.out.println("Starting one-minute countdown now...");
                    Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);

                    // do the thing
                    outOfTime = true;
                    System.out.println("Out of time!");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        countdown.start();

        while (!outOfTime) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("do other stuff here");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While this worked, more-or-less, it seemed like there should be a better way of doing this.

After some searching, I found a bunch of questions like these but they don't really address what I'm trying to do:

- [How do I schedule a task to run at periodic intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544197/how-do-i-schedule-a-task-to-run-at-periodic-intervals)
- [How i can run my TimerTask everyday 2 PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375882/how-i-can-run-my-timertask-everyday-2-pm)
- [How to run certain task every day at a particular time using ScheduledExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387881/how-to-run-certain-task-every-day-at-a-particular-time-using-scheduledexecutorse)
- [Java execute task with a number of retries and a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751329/java-execute-task-with-a-number-of-retries-and-a-timeout/)

I don't need anything this complicated; I just want to do a single thing after a certain amount of time while letting the rest of the program still run.

How should I go about scheduling a one-time task to "do a thing"?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

While the [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) used to be a good way to schedule future tasks, it is now preferable<sup>1</sup> to instead use the classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

There is a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) that is designed specifically to run a command after a delay (or to execute them periodically, but that's not relevant to this question).

It has a [`schedule(Runnable, long, TimeUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method that

> Creates and executes a one-shot action that becomes enabled after the given delay.

Using a `ScheduledExecutorService` you could re-write your program like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Scratch {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting one-minute countdown now...");
        ScheduledFuture<?> countdown = scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do the thing
                System.out.println("Out of time!");
            }}, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        while (!countdown.isDone()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("do other stuff here");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }
}
```

One of the nice things you get by doing things this way is the `ScheduledFuture<?>` object you get back from calling `schedule()`.

This allows you to get rid of the extra `boolean` variable, and just check directly whether the job has run.

You can also cancel the scheduled task if you don't want to wait anymore by calling its [`cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) method.

<sup>1</sup>See [Java Timer vs ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice) for reasons to avoid using a `Timer` in favor of an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: will this scheduled executor run once or every minute. I want mine to run just once and exit.

Comment: @qualebs In this example the action will run just once.  The time being passed into the `schedule()` method is the delay before the action is run.

Comment: @azurefrog yes, it's running just once and I hope the `countdown` object is getting the value from the `TimeUnit` provided here as 1 minute. How can this code be modified to run continuously every 1 minute?, I mean just the opposite way of your code behaviour right now

Comment: Why not use a CountDownLatch to replace the count down object implemented by ScheduleService?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked for me. I used scheduler to schedule a task at a batchinterval calculated at runtime.

```
    manualTriggerBatchJob.setSchedulingProperties(pblId, batchInterval);
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =
            scheduledExecutorService.schedule(manualTriggerBatchJob,
            batchIntervalInMin,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```