# how to re-execute line after x amount of seconds

Tags: java, timer

I have a glitch in my program where it takes way too long to execute a line of code,

So i thought of adding a timer to keep track of how long it takes to execute that line,

And if it takes > 5.5 seconds, re-execute the line.

But here's the problem,

How can i make it so that the timer is executing at the same time the line of code is executing?

I tried this:

```
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //condition

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println(elapsedTime);

    if(elapsedTime > 5500) {
        System.out.println("things are taking too long");

        //re-execute condition
    }
```

Lets pretend the condition did take more than 5.5 seconds. My program wouldn't know the value of `elapsedTime` until **after** the condition executes, and I need to be able to have the value of `elapsedTime` **at the same time** the condition is executing so that if at any time the condition takes longer than 5.5 seconds, the program re-executes that line. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: See answer to [How do I schedule a task to run once?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324083/5221149) for how to schedule a task to run 5 seconds later. When your condition ends, call `cancel()` so the scheduled task won't run (unless it already did). The `cancel()` method is mentioned at the end of the answer.